# I need to update my dev database with my live database

Tags: mysql, database, phpmyadmin

I was handed a side project that I do not have much experience in, so I really appreciate any help. I have two databases on a server, the live database in use, and a dev database which is now an outdated copy of the live database. I need to update the dev database to a current copy that the live database is in, with all current data. It is a mysql database and I am accessing it through parallels and phpMyAdmin. I assume there is a way in phpMyAdmin, possibly with an export and import, I just don't want to screw anything up on the live side.

Comment: I would normally do this through mysqldump, not phpmyadmin, but i'd be surprised if there wasn't a way to also do it through phpmyadmin.

Comment: Step 1 is to make a backup. But in this case, step 1 is the only step you need! Just restore the backup to somewhere else!

Comment: May be mysqladmin will generate incorrect character set file, mysqldump will works fine.

Answer (score 0):

Alright this was easily solved, I'm just coming back to close out the question.

Within cPanel parallels, when you access your various databases, there is a "copy" link on the right side of each row that will copy the selected database's info into another.